# Why can't I have a mailer method named message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've created a new mail on rails 5 using the mailer generator:

```
$ rails g mailer mymailer message
```

Rails created the application_mailer, mymailer_mailer, views and tests. Ok.

This is the mailer generated by rails:

```
class MymailerMailer < ApplicationMailer

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.mymailer_mailer.message.subject
  #
  def message
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end
```

But whenever I've tried to send the mail I've got the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `reject!' for nil:NilClass
```

After spent about two hours double-checking every config file I've decided to change method to `bla`...

Voilà: It worked, Ok! But why?

BTW: *The `message` method I've found is from `ActionMailer::MessageDelivery` but there's no mention on Rails Guides of that.*

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs for [`MessageDelivery`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html), there appears to be a method already provided named `message` which

> Returns the resulting Mail::Message

My assumption is that your definition is overriding this provided method, but you are not returning the expected Mail::Message type object.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer stated, there's already a method in the class named `message`. This shouldn't be a problem if you use the class as intended, since the mailer shouldn't have a single message named "message", it should have a more descriptive name.

The intent of a `Mailer` object is to define a *context for messages that may be sent*.

So for example, a `UserMailer` would be used to build messages to a user. Then each different type of message has a method, such as `forgotten_password` or `welcome`.

The documentation includes [a more thorough example](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#edit-the-mailer) that follows this.